# How to update entity objects without deleting?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an entity generated from my database that contains one table. When i make changes in the DB i obviously would like these changes to reflected in my model.

My current approach is to delete the item from the designer and then right-click - update model from database. This works for me at the moment. Is there a different approach to refreshing these entity tables ?

Comment: I haven't touched EF for years, and its "ability" to deal with data-model changes was the reason I dropped it in the first place.  I hear it's better now though...

Answer (score 1):

Why are you deleting them? You can simply right click on your model and select *Update Model From Database...* and you are done.